# Accept user input in local language

Tags: html, jquery, forms, input, localization

I want to allow the user enter the input in their local language in a html form field. Ex., their name. Is it possible. Any plugins or other info available? I saw "lang" attribute, but that is different it seems. Please advise.

Comment: Search for "localization". There are thousands of plugins and libraries available.

Comment: Can explain why `<input type='text'>` isn't adequate, for user input?

Comment: <input type='text'> means user can enter only English, not any other language. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What "other languages" are you considering?   Have you tried it?  By "English" do you mean "Anglicised"?  There's not really such a thing as an English "name".

Comment: I want Telugu text to be entered by the user. please see as in here https://snipboard.io/elvdSc.jpg  I tried to apply a telugu font to the text input field, but not working. Do I have to use a translator (like google English to telugu) or ?

Comment: [Works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/ujmgdL3s/) for me - have you tried it?   Not sure how you generate the characters - is there a Telugu keyboard?  Characters are in unicode and the input accepts unicode.

Comment: Actually I do not have telugu keyboard. used google translate and copy/pasted that telugu text into the input field. worked fine. Thank you.